# How to specify postgres table columns as variables in python?

Tags: python, postgresql, class

So I have a table that is being updated with new columns every time a new instance of a class is being instantiated. Here's my code doing that.

```
query = "alter table test add column %s integer"
rows = (str(Driver.count), str(Driver.count+1))
for c in rows:
    cur.execute(query, (AsIs(c),))
conn.commit()
```

Driver.count is the counter that is being incremented every new instance of the class. Now when I want to update the table, I use a command similar to this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (str(Driver.count), str(Driver.count+1)) \
VALUES (%d, %d)" % (currentRow,currentCol));
```

Where the two columns I am specifying are variables. I know the above command won't work, since the column variables somehow need to be outside of the quotations, like when I specify the values to be inserted. How can I do this?

Comment: Your column names will be numbers, is that correct?

Comment: John's answer will work for you, but you should know that it is a bad idea to use numbers as column names. If possible, you should prepend some text to number, like `dc1, dc2, ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO test ("%d", "%d") VALUES (%d, %d)'
    % (Driver.count, Driver.count+1, currentRow, currentCol))
```

Or using newer syntax:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO test ("{}", "{}") VALUES ({}, {})'.format(
    Driver.count, Driver.count+1, currentRow, currentCol))
```

Comment: If those column names are numbers, this may still error out (in PostgreSQL). You will need to make sure the column names have double quotes around them. So something like: `... 'INSERT INTO test ("{}", "{}") VALUES ({}, {})'.format(...`

Comment: That is still not correct. You *have* to use double-quotes, not single-quotes.